# Content not displayed in facebook app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-canvas

I am developing a facebook app for displaying products from magento store to facebook app. I have configured my product list page into canvas page correctly. I am getting following response when I try with facebook developer debug tool:
[image]

I get the response as I expected. But when I try to display content in facebook app, it show following output. 
[image]
What is the issue I am facing and what is the solution for this issue ?

Comment: have you configured the HTTPS url, or if not calling it via https:// ? the error suggest that facebook is unable to connect your server

Comment: Check first your Web server allow to display your page in '<iframe>'

Comment: can't even read that font color :)

Comment: @Ahmad: sorry. thats "When I call the link in appcentre, the content not displaying..."

Comment: @Rufinus: Yes I configured for both canvas and pagetab sections bro.

Comment: @balajimca thats not what i asked you :D as you may know you can access FB and all apps via http and https... but if you dont have https configured in your sever and access FB per https facebook will not be able to include your page as it will "the operation timed out"

Comment: @Rufinus How to configure https in server bro ? I dont know how to do it.

Comment: google it, or in the meantime switch your facebook account to not use HTTPS so you can continue developing.