# Rails facebook canvas app on EC2 works via url but not in canvas iframe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2, facebook-canvas

I have a facebook canvas app, and it previously was hosted on Heroku and worked fine.  I recently moved it to ec2, and it works fine when I access it by putting the ec2 url into the browser, but when I try to open the app on facebook itself (where it would be in an iframe), I get "The operation timed out" that looks exactly like this [Content not displayed in facebook app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896967/content-not-displayed-in-facebook-app)."

When I check my production.log, I noticed that it hasn't even gotten to the start of my index action in my main controller (I have it log that it's starting the index action), so it stops long before any oauth issues.

I thought it might be due to not setting it up for https access (an issue I don't entirely understand), so I went to nginx.conf, which had this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    root "my folder here"
    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

I added the following within the brackets, but I don't really understand what the second line does.

```
listen 443 default ssl;
passenger_set_cgi_param HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO https;
```

It still doesn't work though.  Any ideas?

UPDATE: I tried both the http and https versions of the url of my app outside of facebook, and the http works but the https doesn't, so it's likely that the two lines I added above are not enough and my problem relates to that.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I need an SSL certificate and I didn't realize it.